# Reactjs: How to bind multiple values in a state which having different components with may attributes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

App component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';    
import './App.css';    
import { render } from 'react-dom';    
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router';    
import Form from 'react-router-form'    

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         companyName: ''
         designation: ''
      }

      this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
   };

   updateState(e) {

      this.setState({companyName: e.target.value});

      this.setState({designation: e.target.value});

   }

  render() {    
    return ( 
      <div className="form-style-5">
        <h2>Register here</h2>
        <form name="details" action="/hello">
          <Company nameProp={this.state.companyName} desiProp={this.state.designation} updateProp={this.updateState}/>
          <Account/>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Company component:

```
class Company extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <span>
           <legend><p class="number">1</p>Company details</legend>

           Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" value={this.props.nameProp} onChange={this.props.updateProp}/>

           Designation <input type="text" name="designation" value={this.props.desiProp} onChange={this.props.updateProp}/>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Account component:

```
class Account extends Component {    
  render() {    
    return (    
      <span>    
          <legend><p class="number">2</p>Account details</legend>    
          Name <input type="text" name="name"/>
          Email <input type="email" name="email"/>
          Login id <input type="text" name="loginId"/>
          Password <input type="password" name="password"/>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to use all the form values in the next page. So I'm using state. But One value is binding. I can't bind multiple values.

Comment: Format your question properly please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a setState , pass the entire object. Such as ,

```
this.setState({companyName: "your value", designation: "your value"});
```